# Devise gem initialization with AWS OpsWorks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, aws-opsworks

**Background Info:** I have made a Ruby on Rails application that utilizes the ruby gem Devise. When using the gem I have configured the gem's secret key in OpsWorks console as an environment variable.

[image: Environment Variables in OpsWorks console]

When running the `before_migrate.rb` deployment hook I run the command `rake assets:precompile`. But I receive an error in the deployment log.

```
execute "rake assets:precompile" do
   cwd release_path
   command "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
   environment "RAILS_ENV" => rails_env
end
```

> Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[rake
>   assets:precompile]'
>       Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
>
> Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
>   ---- Begin output of bundle exec rake assets:precompile  --trace ---- STDOUT:  STDERR:
>
> ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
>   ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute assets:environment
>
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute environment rake aborted! Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:
>
> config.secret_key = '*****'

I know the environment variables are eventually being set because in my `before_migrate.rb` file I output the environment variables to log. When I hard code the `config.secret_key` everything works correctly.

**Question:** When using OpsWorks do the initializers `config/initializers/*` from my project get run before any of the environment variables get set? Is there another way around this without hard coding keys or SSHing into every instance?

Comment: Were you not able to access it simply by **config.secret_key = ENV[ 'SECRET_KEY_BASE' ]** ?

Comment: That's correct. I tried that first, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to [access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/apps-environment-vars.html) the environment variable in the chef recipe by,

```
node[:deploy]['<YOUR_APP_SHORT_NAME>'][:environment_variables][:SECRET_KEY_BASE]
```

So you can write a recipe to put secrets.yml or something.yml with the environment value.
Create a template,

**your_cookbook/templates/default/secret.yml.erb**

```
secret_key: <%= node[:deploy]['<YOUR_APP_SHORT_NAME>'][:environment_variables][:SECRET_KEY_BASE] %>
```

You can place the **secret.yml** in **/data/YOUR_APPLICATION_SLUG_NAME/shared/config** by a recipe.

**your_cookbook/recipes/default/secret.rb**

```
template "/data/#{<YOUR_APP_SLUG_NAME}/shared/config/secrets.yml" do
  source "secrets.yml.erb"
  owner 'OWNER'
end
```

And make sure that you are symlinking the secrets.yml in shared/config folder to your release path in before_migrate.rb in your deploy hooks.

**your_code_path/deploy/before_migrate.rb**

```
run "ln -nfs /data/<YOUR_APP_SLUG_NAME>/shared/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
```

And have the recipe `your_cookbook::secret` in your deploy life cycle event.

Now you would have generated secrets.yml in your code path/config. You have to load that yaml and set it in config/initializer/devise.rb

```
config.secret_key = <SECRET KEY FROM THE YML GENERATED>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try, and let you know how it turns out.